# In the Persona 4 manga, do Souji and Rise end up dating?

Tags: persona4

I've been looking all over the Internet to find out whether Souji Seta and Rise are a couple in the manga. I have seen many places that say they are, but they are all from 6 years ago.

So my question is, are Rise and Souji Seta actually dating in the manga, and if so, in which volume do they start dating?

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Is there any reason you can't find this out for yourself by simply reading the manga?

Comment: I just wanted to know I just bought the first four and plan on getting the rest soon. I just wanted to know so I could get hyped for it

Comment: Fair enough. I'll see if I can find out for you.

Comment: Thanks man I have look every where and couldn't find anything